# How to create layout field in sitecorefakedb?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

How do you create a layout field using sitecore fakedb? I have the code below but it does not work.

The below code throws an error "the item is not a layout/rendering field"

```
var template = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbTemplate("themes", Templates.SiteTheme.ID);

                var home = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("home", new Sitecore.Data.ID());                

                var lookUpField = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbField("link", Templates.SiteTheme.Fields.SiteTheme) {
                    Type = "Rendering"
                };

                lookUpField.Value = home.ID.ToString();

                var site = new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("site", new Sitecore.Data.ID(), Theming.Templates.SiteTheme.ID) {
                    lookUpField
                };          

                home.Add(site);

                db.Add(home);                

                var themesItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home/site");

               var layout = new LayoutField(themesItem.Fields["link"]);

                var value = layout.Value;

                Xunit.Assert.NotNull(value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
[TestCase]
public void FooLayout()
{
    // arrange
    var itemId = ID.NewID;
    using (var db = new Db
    {
        new DbItem("Some Item", itemId)
        {
            new DbField(Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField) { Value = "{presentation-xml}" }
        }
    })
    {
        var item = db.GetItem(itemId);
        // act
        // assert
        item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField].Should().Be("{presentation-xml}");
    }
}
```

Note: Should().Be() methods come from https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions/